# Phantom DSL questions on set contains and sorting

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I have written this scala code using Phantom DSL to query cassandra

```
  def getByGenreAndYear(genre: List[String], year: Int) : Future[Seq[Movie]] = {
    var criteria = select.where(_.genre contains genre.head)
    criteria = genre.tail.foldLeft(criteria){(accum, i) => accum.and(_.genre contains i)}
    criteria.and(_.year eqs year)
    criteria.allowFiltering().fetch()
  }
```

It works but I have a few questions

- Set Contains

When querying whether a set contains values. is it right to build the query criteria like I have done? basically I have a AND clause for every value for which we want to check. Could this have been done in a single shot like

```
select.where(_.genre contains genreList)
```

- Sorting

I am not able to generate the sort query. when I try to do

```
  def getByGenreAndYear(genre: List[String], year: Int) : Future[Seq[Movie]] = {
    var criteria = select.where(_.genre contains genre.head)
    criteria = genre.tail.foldLeft(criteria){(accum, i) => accum.and(_.genre contains i)}
    criteria.and(_.year eqs year)
    criteria.orderBy(_.year desc)
    criteria.allowFiltering().fetch()
  }
```

The code desn't even compile

Comment: Could you specify the exact compilation error? The table schema is not here either, there's only so much clairvoyance I can exercise on a Monday morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Contains queries**

You cannot do `contains` queries on multiple values at the same time. You have several ways of achieving the above. The first is to use filtering and build a query.

```
def getByGenreAndYear(genre: List[String], year: Int): Future[Seq[Movie]] = {
    val rootQuery = select.where(_.genre contains genre.head)
    genre.tail.foldLeft(rootQuery){ (accum, i) => accum.and(_.genre contains i)}
   .and(_.year eqs year)
   .orderBy(_.year desc)
   .allowFiltering().fetch()
  }
```

This is what you are doing here except the phantom query builder is **immutable**, every single operation you do will create a new `Query` instance. There is a very good reason for that.

The other way is to to sequence futures and not filter in Cassandra, which is not always very advisable.

```
def getByGenreAndYear(genre: List[String], year: Int): Future[Seq[Movie]] = {
  // This will create a future to query for a single value.
  val futures = genre.map(item => select.where(_.year eqs year).and(_.genre contains item).fetch())
  // This will sequence the entire set, produce a list of lists, flatten it and create an union, and deduplicate by set conversion granted you define the right `hashCode` method on the `Movie` class.
  Future.sequence(futures) map {
   // You could also probably get away with lists.flatten
   lists => lists.foldRight(Nil)((item, acc) => item ::: acc)).toSet
  }
}
```

At this point in time doing a `CONTAINS` query is not possible against multiple values in a single query. You get an error:

`cql
select * from marvis.expenses where tags contains ('food', 'office-food');
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid tuple type literal for value(tags) of type text"`

This however works:

`select * from marvis.expenses where tags contains 'food' and tags contains 'office-food' ALLOW FILTERING;`

**Sorting**

To achieve sorting, you need a **Compound** or **Composite** key, and you can only sort by the `clustering key` part of the column, not the **Partition key** part. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://outworkers.com/blog/post/a-series-on-cassandra-part-2-indexes-and-keys) for more details on Cassandra indexing if need be.